# Comparison in R

Tags: r, comparison

I am writing some code for a statistics class and I don't know how I can compare two values in R.

Basically I want the programm to give me a statment like:

```
Z<A
Z>A
Z=A
```

etc.

Z and A are definied by other operations in the code. How do I get R to do this?

Comment: Stack overflow is not suited for questions one can easily answer with a google search

Comment: I did not find it on Google and we also did not have it in class.

Comment: It would be great if you can provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your data. Also, your question is not very clear, what is your desired output? Maybe you can also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: not `=` but `==` also look there: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_operators.htm

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.